# Error trying to save an entity to a postgres using spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple application that has an entity called customer. When I try to save a new customer I get the following error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "customer" does not exist
```

Here Is the code for the entity:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
```

And here the jpa repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {
}
```

And here is the application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: customer
  datasource:
    password: 12345
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/islam
    username: islam
    jpa:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: create
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
          format_sql: true
      show-sql: true
```

Comment: Have you created a table named `customer` in your database?

Comment: no i have not . But I set ddl-auto to create

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: And I think that should be under `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` not `spring.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`?

Comment: It worked now when I did spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto. Thank you very much for the great help @tgdavies

Comment: spring boot would be much better if it at least printed a warning when it saw a property it didn't recognise.

Comment: Yeah I spent a lot of hours figuring out what is wrong with my code while nothing was.